# Wordpress Counter not functioning properly

Tags: wordpress, counter

I'm using "Counter Number Showcase" plugin to display counters in my WordPress website, The problem I'm facing is: If the website is reloaded then the numbers are shown correctly. But if the user scrolls down the page and comes back to the counter section then incorrect values are shown.

Also, an error stating

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shift' of null occurs

Comment: Is there showing line number?

Comment: Please see this link https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up/issues/10

Comment: Yes, Line number 8

Comment: It did not work

Comment: Okay, tell me file  name is also please

Comment: @GufranHasan is there a way in which these numbers should be loaded only once? so that the script doesnt load again and show inaccurate numbers

Comment: jquery.counterup.min is the name of the file

Comment: I think you need to contact with plugin support team first https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/counter-number-showcase